# Check multiple cells in excel, move to next cell if null and if value found stop and return that value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In the below excel table, I am looking for a formula/vba code will the following Problem Statement:

- If cell A2 is empty, go to cell B2, if cell C2 is empty go to cell D2. and if value is present in cell D2 return its value in results cell E2.

[image: Description explained above]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [ask]. StackOverflow is not a service for writing programs for free. You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code. If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this formula:

`=INDEX(FILTER(A2:D2,A2:D2<>""),1,1)`

INDEX returns the first value of the FILTERed (=all non-empty cells) result

[image]

To select non-adjecent cells you can use this formula (Excel 365 only)

```
=LET(data,CHOOSECOLS(A1:F1,1,3,5,6),
@FILTER(data,data<>""))
```

Comment: Or simply `=@FILTER(A2:D2,A2:D2<>"")`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what if the columns are not in series and we have columns as A,C,E,F etc